# When does a real analytic space admit a compatible complex analytic structure?

Tags: complex-geometry

A complex manifold can be viewed as a smooth manifold. A smooth manifold together with an integrable almost complex structure can be given a complex structure.

Clearly a complex analytic space can be viewed as a real analytic space. My question is now, does there exist a concept on real analytic spaces similar to an almost complex structure on a smooth manifold. And does the "integrability" of such a structure imply that there exists a complex structure on this space such that the associated real analytic space is equal or at least isomorphic to the real analytic space one started with.

Comment: What do you precisely mean for real/complex analytic spaces?

Comment: I mean a locally ringed space locally isomorphic to $\left(\text{supp}\left(\mathcal{O}_{K^n}/ J\right),\mathcal{O}_{K^n}/ J\right)$, where $J$ is a coherent ideal sheaf and $K=\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}$. If it helps you may assume that the real analytic spaces are reduced, i.e. varieties.